# disrupting vs. disrupted

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

I have a question regarding *"disrupting"* vs. *"disrupted"* as an adjective.

If I say:

> "These companies have had disrupted effects on the economy"

is the use of *"disrupted"* grammatically correct? Should I use *"disrupting"* instead of *"disrupted"*?

Comment: Consider who is doing the action.

Comment: Disrupting influences have _disruptive_ effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjectives which end in -ing show an active property.
Adjectives which end in -ed show a passive property.
For example :
a)Read the *following* information.
Read the information which follows what you're reading.
b)I am being *followed*.
Someone else is following me. I'm not the one performing the action.

Comment: So you mean "disrupting" is appropriate in this case?

Comment: Exactly, because the effects you mention disrupt the economy

Comment: My pleasure!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

‘Disrupted’ in this sentence would refer strictly to the ‘effects’ (not to ‘on the economy’), so the companies would have been doing something to the effects. Technically that would be possible, but it makes for a strange meaning, and grammatically ugly if not incorrect.

I assume you want to say the companies had a certain type of ‘effects on the economy’, in which case you have to use ‘disrupting’ or perhaps even better ‘disruptive’ (that choice could be a question on its own).